# CSS Sprites Repeating Images

Tags: html, css, optimization, image, css-sprites

I was wondering if there is any way to use just one image for repeating and non-repeating images using css sprites.
So in this case I would like to combine all the images on a page no matter what width and height and if they will be used as repeating or non-repeating images.
I know the standard is to create 1 image using all the non-repeating images and another image using all the repeating images. But i just wanted to know if i could just use 1 image for everything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

The short answer is "no".

The explanation is that repeating images are displayed in their entirety in whatever direction they repeat. So, a background that is set to `repeat-x` will show all image content in the horizontal direction. This is why you can't repeat in both directions simultaneously using sprites.

Comment: Finally the right answer, this needs to be at the top and selected. Sorry ryan that the OP gave up on this thread.

Answer (score 2):

> I know the standard is to create 1
>   image using all the non-repeating
>   images and another image using all the
>   repeating images.

I think you are mistaken. It's impossible to selectively tile a segment of an image. You can only tile an image in its entirety. Thus, all repeating images must live in their own image files.

Comment: No im pretty sure you can repeat images using sprites

This is how
    div {
        background-image:url(sprite8.png);
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
        width: 160px;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 20px;
        float: left;
    }

Examples:
http://www.phpied.com/background-repeat-and-css-sprites/


http://spriteme.org/demo.php

Comment: You can, in fact, repeat images using sprites, but only horizontally OR vertically (exclusive). And the images have to be the same height (vertical) or width (horizontal) to be in the same file with each other.

Comment: Ryan is correct. You can bundle your repeating images in a sprite...one for repeat-x and one fore repeat-y. HOWEVER, in both cases, you'd have to know the maximum width and height respectively. Since I rarely want to commit to that, I often do just keep repeating backgrounds in their own separate files.

Answer (score 2):

@Ryan Kinal is right when saying in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356357/css-sprites-repeating-images/3356396#3356396) that a sprite image can't be used for repeating background images (in both directions).

There is still a way to do it cross-browser with only one or two files (not images), but it isn't that simple and should prove complicated to modify (though sprites are also complicated to modify, but at least it's visual!).

- [**data: base64 encoding**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124149/embedding-background-image-data-into-css-as-base64-good-or-bad-practice) for modern browsers and IE8+
- [**MHTML**](http://www.phpied.com/mhtml-when-you-need-data-uris-in-ie7-and-under/) for IE7 and below (see comments for IE7 on Vista), rediscovered or translated by Stoyan Stefanov

As stated in the PHPIED article, the inline images are repeated twice but with the help of 3 conditional comments you can aim IE7 and below with the MHTML file, IE8 and above with the data: base 64 file and !IE with the same data file.

You end up with 5 different files on your server and 4 downloaded by any given browser:

- an image with `no-repeat`-ing sprites
- an image with `repeat-x`-ing sprites
- an image with `repeat-y`-ing sprites
- a file for MHTML (should be served to IE7 and below) background-images
- a file for the same repeating background images but data encoded for IE8+ and !IE browsers

Large repeating images shouldn't be encoded as filesize could increase a lot, your design may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't force both kinds of images to work on same sprite. Usually repeating image is a little part of a larger image (gradient) that could be repeated in order to save on loading time and size. You can repeat images horizontally, vertically and both. 
`repeat-x`, `repeat-y` or just `repeat` for both. For non repeating images on the sprite you need to indicate scroll coordinates such as `scroll 60px -20px` (60px is left coordinate and -20px is top coordinate).