# What does data:image/png;base64 mean?

Tags: html, css

I took an example from an online website and the CSS contained a URL pointing to a png and some random letters in both cases can any one tell me how to make such codes or rather what those codes are about ...

here is the html

```
<center><input class="textbox"type="text" placeholder="E-mail"></center>
```

here is the css

```
.textbox { 
background: url(data:image/png;base64,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) no-repeat 245px 0px #FFF; 
height: 20px; 
width: 275px; 
    border: 1px solid #848484; 
    color: black; 
}
```

I want to know what those letters and numbers mean i.e () or rather what it is and how can I convert my own png to that . Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Images in CSS or HTML as data/base64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258057/images-in-css-or-html-as-data-base64)

Comment: @hakre Its not a Duplicate ..... i haven't asked whether using Base64 encoding is a good practice? Are there some reasons to avoid this? Are there some major browser that don't have data url support? .....all that i have asked is what it is and the ways to convert an image into Base64 ..... by the way thanks for that link ..... helped me to understand more about base64 encodings

Comment: hi Vicky, that is available in the specification/request-for-comments documents, you can find an introduction to it via the wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme - it lists the specification documents at the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

That is nothing but a [`Base64`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded image.

---

Would like to warn you that Base64 has length limitations

> Although Mozilla supports data URIs of essentially unlimited length,
>   browsers are not required to support any particular maximum length of
>   data. For example, the Opera 11 browser limits data URIs to around
>   65000 characters.

1. [Common problems - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/data_URIs#Common_problems)
2. [Browser Support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri)
3. [Online Converter](http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter)

Comment: @Mr.Alien Can you please look into my question and help me http://stackoverflow.com/q/24078704/2118383

Answer (score 2):

It’s a [**data URI**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

While HTTP URIs refer to *external* resources, data URIs *include* the resources in-line.

By default data URIs use US-ASCII (+ percent-encoding); you can use base64 encoding with `;base64.`.

#### Examples

This data URI is a text document in UTF-8, containing only the word "foobar":

```
data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,foobar
```

This one is a HTML5 document:

```
data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3C%21DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0D%0A%3Chtml%3E%0D%0A%3Chead%3E%3Ctitle%3E%3A-%29%3C%2Ftitle%3E%3C%2Fhead%3E%0D%0A%3Cbody%3E%3A-%29%3C%2Fbody%3E
```

Encoded with base64, that HTML document would look like:

```
data:text/html;charset=utf-8;base64,PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw+DQo8aHRtbD4NCjxoZWFkPjx0aXRsZT46LSk8L3RpdGxlPjwvaGVhZD4NCjxib2R5PjotKTwvYm9keT4=
```

Simply enter these URIs into the address field of your browser, like you would do with HTTP URIs.

Answer (score 0):

That's a base64 encoding of a PNG image file.