# data-ng-src method call with $http runs into an infinite loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

::::::hmtl logic:::::

```
<img class="imageCss" ng-src="{{getImage(id)}}">
```

::::angular js method in the controller scope::::

```
$scope.getImage = function getImage(id){
    console.log("in getImages");
    console.log("id " + id);

    var testData = $http.get('http:/images/getImage.do?imageId='+id).then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        return result;
    });
    //console.log("testData " + testData);
}
```

This method call from `ng-src` triggers an infinite loop. I am suspecting the http request is doing this. I have no clue what is going wrong here.

Can someone please help me this?

Comment: So, you need to make an HTTP call to get the URL of each image? That seems suspicious. BTW, your function doesn't return anything. I guess you simply need `<img class="imageCss" ng-src="http://images/getImage.do?imageId={{id}}">`

Comment: Yes, JB Nizet. The intention here is to use the id to make a http call to get the acutual image. The image here is a png image. Is something wrong with this logic? I tried using the url, but with the setup we have it is not possible to use the url directly (because of some security reasons)

Comment: What ng-src expects is not the image. It's the URL of the image. And the URL of the image is `http://images/getImage.do?imageId={{id}}`. Once the image src attribute is set, the browser will do the HTTP request to download the image. You must not do it yourself. And BTW, even if it did expect the image, your function doesn't return anything. And even if it did return something, Angular would call it at each $apply, and your code would re-download it again and again and again. So there are many, many things wrong with your logic.

Comment: Thanks, JB Nizet. I think I understood the concept here. Man!! Angular JS in confusing :)

Answer (score 1):

The infinite loop is caused because:

1. `$http` will call `$apply` function implicitly, which will start `$digest`
2. `$digest` evaluates the `ng-src` again.
3. Then `ng-src` will call the function `getImage`
4. `getImage` will invoke the `$http`
   ...

You can just use `ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{imageSrc[id]}}"` in HTML, and in controller:

```
$scope.imageSrc = {};
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    var id = ids[i];
    $http.get('http:/images/getImage.do?imageId='+id).then(function (data) {
        $scope.imageSrc[id] = data;
    });
}
```

After the `for` loop, the `imageSrc` object will be like:

```
{
    1: 'binary content of the image',
    11: 'binary content of the image',
    20: 'binary content of the image',   
    ...
}
```

Then the `imageSrc` will be updated automatically after the `$http` request finishes.

Comment: Thanks, Joy. Don't we have to wrap the http call inside a method? Can I just call $http in my controller?

Comment: I have to use the id to get the image from the server. How can I do it here?

Comment: Thanks, Joy. What does imageSrc[id] do? In the example you gave above, are you assuming that ids are saved in some data structrue, and you are getting the id from the structure?

Comment: Your url `http:/images/getImage.do?imageId=` is getting the binary content of the image or only the url string of the image?

Comment: It is getting the binary content of the image

Comment: Thanks, Joy. So, if we have 100 images, Are all the 100 images placed correctly (if I am using a list sorted by the id), after the for loop is processed?

Comment: Yes. The 100 requests are simultaneously issued and fill the `imageSrc` object after return.

Comment: Awesome! one last question. I'm gettting all bytes from server. Do I have to use base64 in ng-src

Comment: Please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20088554/what-does-dataimage-pngbase64-mean

Comment: Thanks much, Joy. This is very useful information. I shall take a look at the link you posted.  I really appreciate your help with my question

Comment: @user4122421 My pleasure :) Please kindly upvote/accept if it helps you.