# Jekyll Social Icon's Background Image

Tags: css, fonts, jekyll, font-awesome

Trying to orientate myself with Jekyll. I've downloaded the following theme [Mediator Theme](http://incorporated.sendtoinc.com/). I'm trying to adjust the social icons to show icons for things like Github and Linked in. When I pop over to the _icons.scss file in the _assets folder/stylesheets I see this crazy thing for the background image of the icon. I'm assuming I have to create new icons with a similar format? What on earth is going on with this background image? Has anyone seen this before?

```
.icon-facebook {
background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
background-size:14px;
background-position:0 0;
width:14px;
height:14px;
}
```

What is the background image referencing? I've never seen this before. I figured they were just pulling in the font awesome library but the syntax I'm used didn't work and then I found this. Any help would be greatly apprecaited.

Comment: This link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258057/should-i-embed-images-as-data-base64-in-css-or-html explains it very well.

Comment: thanks i had no idea.