# Caching page: base64 image in HTML vs Image as attachment (separate URL)

Tags: html, image, caching, base64, cloud

**Background:**

We want to build a page that will use dynamic serving (different version for desktop, tablet and mobile).

Currently we think which of the two solutions will serve content faster and be better overall.
I am thinking in context of serving it to different devices (desktop, tablet, mobile) using the same URL.

> Dynamic serving sites: one URL that serves different HTML and CSS depending on the user agent.

source: http://www.vervesearch.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-developing-mobile-websites/

Our main goal is speed. Then other things.

---

**Solutions:**

1) storing images as base64 in HTML

User enters a site. For example it contains 1-2 images that are pretty large. Images are embedded directly into HTML as base64.
We have one minified JS file and one minified CSS file.
So in ideal example we have
- HTML that contains 1-2 large images (they can have up to 5MB).
- one minified CSS file
- one minified JS file

So...
*3 requests*

2) storing images in separate URLs

User enters a site. It contains 1-2 images stored in fastest possible external storage (sidenote: Can I store images as attachment in fastly?).
We have one minified JS file and one minified CSS file.

So we have
- HTML
- one minified CSS file
- one minified JS file
- 1-2 images

So...
3 requests (HTML, JS, CSS) + 2 requests

*5 requests*

---

**Questions:**

Do we gain a lot of speed when using less HTTP calls (connection estabilish latency etc)?
Is it worth it? Base64 encoding bloats image sizes by 33%. source: [Should I embed images as data/base64 in CSS or HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5258057/418518)

Which solution/way is gonna work "better" (faster speed)?
Is it possible to do "each" way?

Can I cache whole 'stuff' (html, js, css, images)?
Will caching works (good for each customer/visitor) if I have a lot of sites to cache?

---

**PS.** If any question looks stupid - sorry we have a very hot discussion in our company and I want to provide all information.

Comment: AFAIK Base64 images can't be cached.

Answer (score 0):

You can try both solutions yourself and compare the results:

http://www.webpagetest.org/compare

and if you want to test for desktop and mobile, try pageSpeed test:

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

you will have the results showing for desktop and mobile, then you can decide which route to go.