# Is there a -moz-mask CSS property, like -webkit-mask-image?

Tags: firefox, css, gradient, mask

It seems `-moz-mask-image` is not supported in Firefox.

I am attempting a foreground gradient. I can't use an image as i need the text to be selectable. Does anyone have any ideas for Firefox?

[This version](http://lustlab.net/projects/dev/tijdexp/grad.php) works in chrome and safari

css:

```
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.16, rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(0.52, rgba(0,0,0,.5)), color-stop(0.77, rgba(0,0,0,1)));

-moz-mask: -moz-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.16, rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(0.52, rgba(0,0,0,.5)), color-stop(0.77, rgba(0,0,0,1)));
```

Comment: Is your background a solid color? You could place a pseudo-element on top of the text going from transparent to the background color.

Comment: Hi Duopixel - yeah I tried this but this results in unselectable text.

Comment: add `pointer-events: none;` to the gradient element.

Comment: I've travelled from future to announce that `mask-image` is finally supported in Firefox 53. Hooray!

Answer (score 4):

According to MDN, you can just use `mask` for Firefox, as of Firefox 3.5:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/mask

However, `mask` requires an SVG image to act as the mask. You might be able to [base-64 encode your SVG image into your stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124149/embedding-background-image-data-into-css-as-base64-good-or-bad-practice), or you can use an SVG image file.

Comment: Except you can't use it with `gradient`, you have to [use SVG instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content).