# cache background image

Tags: css, image, background, cross-browser

Is there a way to "cache" background image.

For example.. 
Background image is 3x3px and it's set like this:

```
body {
    background: #000 url(bg.png);
}
```

When refresh happens, background image "flickers" for second.

Is there a cross-browser solution? (for Apache/PHP server if that is relevant)

---

If you go to seo.hr and browse navigation,... you can see what I'm trying to do.

http://www.seo.hr/

http://www.seo.hr/usluge/izrada-stranica

http://www.seo.hr/usluge/optimizacija-za-trazilice

Comment: Consider making the background image larger, so that there are fewer tiles. Something like 128x128 would be appropriate. It might still flicker, but less noticeably so.

Comment: Are you sure caching is the problem?  Most browsers will cache a background image locally, but it still will take a few fractions of a second to render.  There are probably higher priority items on the render queue.

Comment: @KarmicCoder I'm not sure that is caching problem. But when I for example view some website on localhost server - render time is few milliseconds. If I test the same website on www server (e.g. 2Mbit connection) it takes second or two.

Comment: Make the background image as large as possible but under 10kb. Larger tiles won't have the "flicker".

Comment: This may not apply, but if you are on a secure connection (https) then no caching occurs (nor can it occur).

Comment: Is the flashing you see similar to viewing this page? If you right mouse button -> reload frame I get a flashing effect. http://jsfiddle.net/B43Zg/

Comment: http://www.seo.hr/, http://www.seo.hr/usluge/izrada-stranica, http://www.seo.hr/prodaja/

Those would be an example of what I'm trying to do !!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you need to determine first if the issue actually is a caching issue or if it's caused by the size of your image.  You could use a program like Wireshark or Fiddler to do this, but to be honest it's overkill for your need and you probably already have a browser with developer tools.

Here's how you determine where an image is coming from in Chrome (the other browsers are similar).

1. Open your developer tools and go to the "Network" tab.
2. Find "bg.png" in the list of network requests and click on it's name.  Below is an example of having selected a stack overflow image from this page.

[image: Google Chrome Image Retrieved from Cache]

Notice that it says status 200 (from cache). The browser didn't need to go out to the server and rerequire that resource. It used the cache.  If that "from cache" text wasn't there it wasn't reusing cached resources.

There is also the potential that you'll get a status code of 304.  That means that the server said the image wasn't modified since the last request that you made.  You do make the server trip in that case.

**Ok, so my image wasn't in cache... now what?**

There are a few reasons that this could occur.

1. You're request headers aren't set to tell the browser to cache the image (also found in that same "Headers" tab that you would have seen that Status Code if the browser actually went to the server for the image).  You'll want to set `cache-control` and `expires` to something that makes sense for you. Cache headers can get a bit complicated you may want to browse through [this caching tutorial document](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/).
2. Is it SSL? If so not all browsers cache this but most modern browsers do. Set `cache-control: public` on these images (and also expires).

The real question here is how do you fix this? Unfortunately, that's entirely dependent on the server and/or the framework that you are using. As the OP is using Apache, they can find [great documentation on the Apache module mod_expires to figure out how to tweak caching for their site](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html).

Comment: So how do you enforce caching / specify HTTP headers through a css background property?

Comment: @DrazenBjelovuk I added some information on how to do this in Apache. It really is dependent on what framework and server you are using. The OP was using Apache and PHP. Since it was a static image, Apache would be the best place to reconfigure that caching.

Comment: Then I take it there's no way without control of the server?

Comment: To give a reason why it is not in the cache is not the answer to the question how to cahce the image in localstorage for example

Comment: @DanFroberg why build a cache for images in localStorage when the browser gives you it for free. Especially in 2012 when we didn't have the concept of offline web apps

Answer (score 7):

**Yes**!

You should decide whats more suitable for you, but at this time we have some methods, like:

- Pure HTML/CSS
- Javascript Only
- Mixed HTML/CSS/Javascript
- Using base64 to encode the image somewhere on the source code

At this point I recommend a mixed solution, using javascript. This will make it work on many browsers as possible.

There is a good tutorial at: 
http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/12/28/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/

Having several images in one can take you a step beyond that, so check this sprites article:
 http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites/

Answer (score 1):

You can try to encode your image in base64 and put it directly into CSS source code. I found a question about pros and cons over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124149/embedding-background-image-data-into-css-as-base64-good-or-bad-practice).

Answer (score 0):

Make your tiled image much much larger, when the browser engine renders the page it has to multiply each tile to cover the entire width and length of your object, which results in bad performance with small tiles on large objects.

Small tiles -> more repetitions -> slower performance