# Using same background img for all pages of a website affects loading time?

Tags: html, css, pageload

Does using the same image for every page's background on a website decreases the page load times? I mean will that background image be cached on ur disk after opening one page resulting in a lil bit faster load time for the other pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9035931/722617

You need to determine if the server is sending a cache-header for the files in question