# CSS- loading images from cache

Tags: css, caching

If I am using `background: url` in my `CSS` files like:

```
background: url("/app/assets/imgs/someimage.png") no-repeat !important;
```

Is the image will load from my `cache`(assuming it is there), or it will send a new request for it?

I have checked `chrome://cache/` and the image exists.

Comment: It will be in cache if your css stays in cache

Comment: I guess the answer you looking for is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497855/cache-background-image

Comment: @LuisP.A. so I need to cache my CSS as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to a background image URL in CSS will form a HTTP GET Request within the browser which will first check the local cache for that URL.

So yes - if the file is cached locally, and the URL is exactly the same, it will pull it from the local cache.

Comment: Thanks, that is all I needed to know.