# Fade out hiding the bottom part of a div

Tags: html, css, web, frontend

I'm trying to achieve result like this:

[image: result]

I tried adjusting the height of the div but it affects the content inside, how can I achieve this effect in CSS?

Comment: Post your `Html` and your `CSS` and your attempt.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS3 opacity gradient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597167/css3-opacity-gradient)

Comment: You can find the solution in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597167/css3-opacity-gradient