# Best way to make content appear to be fading away

Tags: html, css, overlay, linear-gradients

I'm trying to accomplish some thing like:
[image]

Where I have the bottom of a div fading into the color of the div that comes after. Not sure what the best way to accomplish this is to use a linear gradient or an image.

I have tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597167/css3-opacity-gradient) and it resulted in this: [image]

Which is close but the fade begins a bit high.

```html
.sumo-section {
    -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, 
    left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
}
```

How should I modify it to get the transition to begin further down the div?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS3 opacity gradient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597167/css3-opacity-gradient)

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković Close, I used the top solution but the fade starts a bit high. How would I use the webkit gradient to start the transition further down the div?

Comment: By changing some values in the gradient part

Comment: @Rana The syntax of webkit-gradient is a bit confusing to me. I know with linear gradient I would put a percent after the rgba value to state where I want the transition to start and finish. Not sure how to accomplish the same idea with webkit

Comment: It is same as normal gradient but have a prefix `-webkit-` so just treat it as normal and enter the values you would in normal gradient

Answer (score 0):

Linear gradient because is rendered by the browser, you have better control and can be dynamic (easier) if you need so. I don't think there is better a reason to use an image instead.