# Apply gradient mask with css

Tags: css, gradient

I am trying to do this 
[Using CSS, can you apply a gradient mask to fade to the background over text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525215/using-css-can-you-apply-a-gradient-mask-to-fade-to-the-background-over-text)
but I want to apply the gradient from top and bottom.

```
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left 30%, left bottom, left top, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)),      to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QZMyd/
but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please test this demo in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/95vPC/5/

```
<div class="element">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit … amet.</p>
</div>
```

---

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.element {
    width: auto;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000045;
    -webkit-mask-position: 0 0;
    /*-webkit-mask-size: 200px 200px;*/
    -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 0)), color-stop(19%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 0.66)), color-stop(29%, rgba(45, 70, 237, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(45, 70, 237, 0)));
}
```

Comment: I am afraid is not what I am looking for. 
I am actually trying to achieve this http://jsfiddle.net/jLT9S/
with one div I have done that with 2 as you can see.

Comment: @daniel__ is it possible to use this without

    background: #000045;