# CSS let background-image overwrite part of background-color

Tags: html, css, gradient

I have a division that I gave a black background color. The body of the HTML is yellow. What I want is the first black div to fade out.

I wanted to do this using a `background-image`. The background image is a `png` file that is black as well, but has a transparency from `0%` on the left and gradually goes to `100%` on the right.

If I also add this `background-image` to my division, it remains black.

I understand why this happens, because the image is transparent, and behind that image is still the black color. I get that. Is there a way to do it though? Is there a way to disregard a `background-color` where a `background-image` is positioned?

I rather don't create extra html elements if it ain't necessary.

Comment: please post the code of what you have tried so far. Even if it is not working like expected. Just post a jsFiddle of it and make it easy to answer

Comment: You could use a gradient as background-image in the first place (use this generator: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/). Or maybe a gradient mask (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525215/using-css-can-you-apply-a-gradient-mask-to-fade-to-the-background-over-text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the linear-gradient CSS function for your div.

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, black, white)
```