# Add circular fading opacity (vignette effect) to images in CSS

Tags: html, css, opacity

I want to give **circular opacity** to an image using CSS.

I know I can achieve opacity on images like this:

```
.circle img {
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
}
```

I know I can achieve circular images like this:

```
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.circle img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
}
```

I want somehow to merge the two things above and apply the opacity only for the edges of the image, so the center of the image gets almost nothing from the opacity tag. I have searched for hours but found nothing.

Without opacity: http://jsfiddle.net/8w6szf84/47

With opacity: http://jsfiddle.net/8w6szf84/48/ -> bad opacity, want only the edges to fade...

Do I need to use Javascript on this? Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you use two (of the same) images and have the outside one with less opacity and have a smaller inside one?

Comment: @Jofish Well if I used that, there would be a line between the two images that would separate them from each other which looks awful. But not a bad thought!

Comment: you can do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/8w6szf84/2/

Comment: Maybe you can combine with radial gradients and opacity ? It's worth a try.  see http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes Same thing as the first comment, I need something that fades as you go out from the image.

Comment: Something like this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8w6szf84/3/) you will need a solid colour background for this to work.

Comment: @balintpekker: This: http://jsfiddle.net/0kpya452/3/ or this:  http://jsfiddle.net/0kpya452/2/

Comment: @Ruddy That is really cool you should make it an answer

Comment: @Ruddy Im with Akshay, nice! Thanks for it!!

Comment: Ah ok @balintpekker oh well

Comment: @balintpekker I have edited my answer, there is a slightly better way to do it so you don't have to set the height or width at all. Hope this has helped you.

Comment: @Ruddy thanks for your help, I do appreciate it!

Comment: @balintpekker Not a problem, was a good question! Don't seem to get many of these nowadays!

Comment: @balintpekker is it OK if I add the words [vignette effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vignetting) in the title? (*if* it is what you wanted).

Comment: @SalmanA If more people could find help here by changing it, and I wanted the same as you linked, it's OK for me. Thank you!

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525215/using-css-can-you-apply-a-gradient-mask-to-fade-to-the-background-over-text

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Ok, so what we can do is create a `:after` element that will be equal to the size of the parent. Using this we can set a background gradient that will make it appear as the image is fading into the **solid** colour background.

**Note:** In this example I have made the gradient element a little bigger and moved it over `1px` to stop a border from appearing around it. From here you can mess around to get the perfect effect that you want.

```css
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.circle img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    border:1px solid #fff;
}
.circle:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 70%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200?image=2" />
</div>
```

---

**Edit:** Here is another version without setting a height or width and getting rid of the border that gets caused if using `100%` of parent. As **Vucko** pointed out we don't need the negative values for the position but can use a `border` around the `img` instead.

[JsFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/8w6szf84/49/)

Comment: I don't know this is what OP required or not, but I like this :)

Comment: Nice one - but I'd change it a little, just to remove the negative values, so check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/on79umkw/).

Comment: @Vucko Ah excellent! Using the border instead, not sure why I didn't think to do that. Have updated the answer to include this.

Comment: @Ruddy yes, `border` removes the "glitch". But also, you don't have to have a fixed `width/height` on the pseudo element (202px) - just use `100%`.

Comment: @Vucko Yeah sorry, I was more concentrating on the edit I did as that answer is better (no width or height needed). I just forgot to change the width and height. Thanks for your help, nice work!

Comment: Is there any way to handle relative `width`/`height` arguments in the `<img />` tag? i.e. go to the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8w6szf84/49/) and add `<img src="http://placeimg.com/200/200/any" width="50%"/>` to the html.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: @mrg95 Hows that? This answer was accepted. I feel like the OP would know what does and doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Ruddy This answer solved their problem, but didn't answer the question. This answer doesn't add fading opacity to the image, it only created the illusion of such an effect by creating a background gradient of the same color as a solid background. This technique wont work for a gradient background, or another image background, for example. This is because this DOESNT add any gradient to the image itself.

It doesn't answer the question. The correct method would be to use css mask. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58071243/radial-gradient-opacity-on-background-image/58071275

Answer (score 7):

you can also use a box-shadow

```css
.shadow {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.shadow img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.shadow:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 10px 24px 40px 0px white, 
    inset -10px -24px 40px 0px white, 
    inset 20px -10px 40px 0px white, 
    inset -20px 10px 40px 0px white;
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow">
  <img src="http://placeimg.com/200/200/any" />
</div>
```

Comment: You need the " at the end of the src attr

Answer (score 6):

You could use two (of the same) images and have the top one smaller and transparent.

```css
.circle-opaque {
    border-radius: 50%;          /* Make it a circle */
    display: inline-block;       
    position: absolute;          /* Able to position it, overlaying the other image */
    left:0px;                    /* Customise the position, but make sure it */
    top:0px;                     /* is the same as .circle-transparent */
    z-index: -1;                 /* Makes the image sit *behind* .circle-transparent */
}
.circle-opaque img {
    border-radius: 50%;          /* Make it a circle */
    z-index: -1;
}
.circle-transparent {
    border-radius: 50%;          /* Make it a circle */
    display: inline-block;       
    position: absolute;          /* Able to position it, overlaying the other image */
    left: 0px;                   /* Customise the position, but make sure it */
    top: 0px;                    /* is the same as .circle-transparent */
    z-index: 1;                  /* Makes the image sit *on top of* .circle-transparent */
}
.circle-transparent img {
    width: 200px;
    opacity: 0.4;                /* Make the second image transparent */
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);   /* For IE8 and earlier; optional */
    z-index: 1;                  /* And on top of the first */
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-opaque">
    <img src="http://www.catchannel.com/images/articles/0805/orange-kitten-200px.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="circle-transparent">
    <img src="http://www.catchannel.com/images/articles/0805/orange-kitten-200px.jpg" />
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/joe_young/20y832r7/

Answer (score 3):

Although this approach isn't as clean as others (possibly due to lack of time), I believe it *could* be cleaned up. However, it's using just box shadows to achieve the look you're thinking of. (Radial gradients would possibly be preferred, although if you need a fallback, this could be an option)

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/300/400);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 
    inset -5px -5px 100px white, 
    inset 0 0 90px white, 
    inset 0 0 80px white, 
    inset 0 0 70px white, 
    inset 0 0 60px white, 
    inset 0 0 50px white, 
    inset 0 0 40px white, 
    inset 0 0 30px white, 
    inset 0 0 20px white, 
    inset 0 0 10px red; 
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Well it's kinda same like Vitorino's answer but this is nice too.

Comment: I can actually say I didn't see theirs. Although, upon looking I can see that theirs involves a few too many elements for my liking. I try to keep markup to a minimum IMHO :P

Answer (score 2):

Here is a modified version of [Ruddy's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27634201/87015) answer except that the diameter of gradient matches the width (or height) of the image instead of diagonal. Border radius is not required. 80% of the image displays as-is, the remaining 20% fades from transparent to white.

```css
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.circle img {
  display: block;
}
.circle:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side at center,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 80%, 
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <img src="http://www.catchannel.com/images/articles/0805/orange-kitten-200px.jpg">
</div>
```

Note that radial gradients are drawn from the specified center; while box shadows are drawn from the edges; therefore both produce different results.

Answer (score 0):

I like simple, so the following might suffice:

```css
.circle {
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse at center center, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 70%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  display: inline-block;
}
.circle img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <img src="http://www.catchannel.com/images/articles/0805/orange-kitten-200px.jpg" />
</div>
```