# Radial gradient opacity on background image

Tags: css, background-image

I need to apply a radial gradient of opacity to a repeating background image.

The proposed solutions online recommend to add another solid color gradient over the image giving the illusion of a fading background image. However, this solid color gradient solution will not work in my case because the background is not a solid color, but rather a linear gradient.

Here is an exaggerated example of what I'm trying to achieve using a bright red repeating background image and a grey to black gradient background.

[image]

How can I *actually* fade a background image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`mask`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask)

```css
.box {
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/600/800) center/cover;
  -webkit-mask:radial-gradient(circle at 20% 40%, transparent , #fff 50%);
          mask:radial-gradient(circle at 20% 40%, transparent , #fff 50%);
}

body {
 background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Comment: Wow that was quick! Works perfectly, I've never heard of mask in css before. Thanks so much!

Comment: This appears to also mask anything inside the div as well. It's not just a mask on the background image. Is there any way to still have other elements show up while inside this div?

Comment: @mrg95 use a pseudo element as a background layer and apply mask to it. Consider it like opacity, if you apply it you will affect all the content

Comment: @mrg95 check this for the pseudo element trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7241440/8620333

Comment: Got it working perfectly! You're a wizard. Thanks again :)

Comment: I'd like to note that this does not function for IE