# CSS Image Vignette effect

Tags: css

So, I'm trying to apply this effect on an image using CSS where it's like Vignette effect, but instead of just shadows, the edges gradually dissolve outwards into the background.

What I mean is, exactly like this image below
[image: Desired output]

I want to apply the effect they have put on "Maps" image (ignore the Pin location), like how those edges have dissolved with the blue background.

I have tried using Box-shadows as follow

```
TestImageProp: {
boxShadow: '0 0 200px rgba(0,0,0,0.9) inset',
border: 'none',
height: '700px',
width: '700px'}
```

and

```
<div className="TestImageProp">
  <img src={TestImage} alt="ArtBackground" height="700px" width="700px"/>
</div>
```

But not getting the desired output. This is what I'm getting instead
[image: Actual output]

Comment: Can you give us a working snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the maps image looks as if the **opacity**  has a circular gradient.

Find the solution here:
[Add circular fading opacity (vignette effect) to images in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27634023/add-circular-fading-opacity-vignette-effect-to-images-in-css)

Comment: Yup! This is the one, thank you very much for pointing me towards the right direction. Much appreciated!