# Making div video background fade - is it possible?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, video, background

I'm creating a website for a client using Wordpress. The top portion of the website is a div with a video as the background. They have requested that the bottom of the video div fade into the background of the website. I can't think of any way to make this happen but I thought I'd look into this and see if there are any possibilities to make this work. Please advise.

See the website here: 
test site: http://www.dankruptmusic.net/wordpress
actual site: http://www.dankruptmusic.net

Thank you all!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: there is a login password required for the test site..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a gradient mask and there is a post on that topic where you should find your solution - [Using CSS, can you apply a gradient mask to fade to the background over text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525215/using-css-can-you-apply-a-gradient-mask-to-fade-to-the-background-over-text)

Also check out this article on the whole masking subject. It might have a simpler example of what you are looking for - https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/