# Can I Fade Out Image With Border-Radius 50%?

Tags: html, css

So, I'm trying to fade out an image that has `border-radius: 50%` but I can't seem to get it down.

```
<section id="main">
  <h1>Non-Important-Text</h1>
  <h4>
    it's all fun and games until you can't find a damn solution....
  </h4>

  <div id="img-container">
    <img src="./assets/1.jpg" />
  </div>
</section>
```

```
/* ... */
#main #img-container {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#main #img-container img {
  width: 30em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

#main #img-container img::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background: radial-gradient(
    ellipse at center,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%
  ); /* This doesn't work! */
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

My Image, is circle, and does have a border. But it doensn't get faded out( in a circular way). How can I achieve that

**Goal**: [image]

**What I Get**: [image]

I tried everything from, `radial-gradient`, `-webkit-gradient`, to even, `-webkit-radial-gradient`. But they all produce the same result!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `mask-image`

```css
div{
background: skyblue;
padding: 20px;
}
img{
-webkit-mask-image: radial-gradient(circle at center, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0, rgba(0,0,0,0) 70%);
  mask-image: radial-gradient(circle at center, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0, rgba(0,0,0,0) 70%);
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto
}
```

```html
<div><img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,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' /></div>
```

Comment: here is another similar question for your references. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525215/using-css-can-you-apply-a-gradient-mask-to-fade-to-the-background-over-text

Comment: glad to help, FYI the display:block & margin on the img is not necessary, just to align the img at the center of the div

Comment: You could improve this answer by changing "circle" to "ellipse".  That way it correctly fades non-square images like in the snippet, i.e., removes the sharp edges on each side.

Comment: @mok_ku yes, I know. That was on purpose : )