# rounded edges to the sides of the DIV

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to give a certain DIV (which contains other elements) rounded edges,I need the other elements inside the DIV to be affected and get the same attribute.

I **don't** mean rounded corners which can be achieved with `border-radius: Xpx;` like this:
[image: Text]

and I **don't** mean such a two-dimensional curve either,like this:
[image: Text]
I mean a 3-dimensional curve like this:
[image: Text]
A relatively simple simulation:
[image: Text]

Comment: So a beveled gradient? Why are you simulating hardware features inside of software?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl to be more beautiful the DIV needs to simulate the behavior of a certain hardware.
(not a phone, it's just for the example, something with rounded edges)

Comment: Please see [ask]. You're expected to make an effort and show some code. Your title should be a clear, specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mask-image` with `linear-gradient`:

```css
body{ /* or any other wrapper */
  background: white;
}
.edge{
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  font-size: 3rem;
  height: 800px;
  width: 400px;

  border-radius:30px;
  
  background: blue;
  --gradient: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 4%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 96%, rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 100%); /* you can modify this for your desire */
  -webkit-mask-image: var(--gradient); 
  mask-image: var(--gradient);
  
}
```

```html
<div class="edge">
   <div>
      hello
   </div>
</div>
```

Related: [Using CSS, can you apply a gradient mask to fade to the background over text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525215/using-css-can-you-apply-a-gradient-mask-to-fade-to-the-background-over-text)

Answer (score -1):

One common way to achieve this is by box-shadow. here is a example:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.curved-rectangle {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #3498db;
  /* Your desired background color */
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px inset white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Curved Rectangular Effect</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="curved-rectangle">
    <div class="content">
      you are the best
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: People (not me) downvote because, as the down vote arrow says, "This answer is not useful" - so one person thinks this is not a good answer...  maybe(?) because a simple box-shadow can't really accomplish the desired result. A non-linear gradient would probably work best, but there's no such thing as, say, a bezier-gradient — only linear, radial, and conic. There are, however, some [techniques that will come closer](https://css-tricks.com/easing-linear-gradients/).