# HTML-Email annoying line-breaking

Tags: php, html, email

I'm digging deep in html-email stuff and finally, i have still an unsolved problem with annoying line-breaks :/

GMail and or Outlook are often breaking the line exactly during a tag - resulting in a completely broken look & feel.. so it can happen that the whole content is in a < h2 > because the ending-tag is broken through a line-break..

```
m</strong><br/>Passwort: <
strong>20o3a7
```

That's an example of a broken e-mail generated by my PHPMailer code..

Now i was fascinated with an email of a company, perfectly styled newsletter.. There i saw a code like this:

```
<table width=3D"100%" cellspacin=
g=3D"0" border=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0">
```

This i can see on almost any line of this strange e-mail -> always ending with "=" on any line, altough if it is in the middle of a tag or a parameter-word.. and it is perfectly working! How that? It seems to me that this line-breaks are generated before it comes to the e-mail client, but this is only speculation of me...

I can find extermely nice articles how to create a correct HTML-Email like this:

http://24ways.org/2009/rock-solid-html-emails

But nobody writes something about this annoying line-break problem, but i can't believe that i'm the only one that has this issue... :/

Comment: As a note, this happens when a line of HTML is considered too long for the email and the mail server breaks the line anywhere.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simple workaround

```
$body = str_replace("<","\r\n<", $body);
```

Every HTML tag will start from new line giving you:

```
m
</strong>
<br/>Passwort: 
<strong>20o3a7
```

---

Another thing is, i used `PHPMailer` in many projects, sending thousands e-mails to all mail clients, and i never experienced that issue. Make sure your code is OK. (maybe your text editor is wrapping that lines?)

Comment: Woaaa you made my day :))

You're simple workaround is working like a charm -> immediately i have no broken mails anymore ind Outlook and GMail...

Just another thing i'm wondering... Do you have an idea why Outlook is deleting my "background: url(an-image-url.jpg)" inline-style-definition on a table-layout's TD element? Any other tested client is rendering perfectly my background-image-styling, but not outlook...

Comment: what about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124149/is-embedding-background-image-data-into-css-as-base64-good-or-bad-practice)

Comment: Note that the =3D in an encoded email represents the character '=' (3D is the ASCII code in hex.)

Comment: Emails shouldn't have more than 70 chars per line for comapitibility reasons. This is why that = line breaking thingy is used. Your code won't work on all email clients if html tags become longer than those 70 characters.

Comment: @ManuelArwedSchmidt you are right, I removed wrong part

Answer (score 3):

> `<table width=3D"100%" cellspacing=3D"0" border=3D"0" cellpadding=`

It's called [quoted printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) encoding which is common for html emails. '=3D' for instance stands for '='.

Regarding to your problem: never occured to me. It's be difficult to debug without beeing able to look at the source. But it seems you got a solution anyway. :)

Comment: thanks for your info anyway ;) i did not have the idea that it could be a kind of encoding

Answer (score 0):

```
$message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$id,2);
$message = quoted_printable_decode($message); // magic
```