# Add background image to div using data uri

Tags: html

I'm trying to set the background of a  using the data uri format, but it's not working. Is it supported?

```
<div id="img_div" style="background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0goKG41........sadasd==);"></div>
```

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NA9Ye/

I edited the data here so my post wouldn't be huge.

THank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is embedding background image data into CSS as Base64 good or bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124149/is-embedding-background-image-data-into-css-as-base64-good-or-bad-practice)

Comment: How is it a duplicate? I'm asking if it is possible to set a div background with it, not if it's a good idea or not to do it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
http://jsfiddle.net/NA9Ye/5/
```

You have to add width and height to div with backgroun-image

```
    #img_div{width:1000px;
height:1000px}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting some content in the div. Or set a height and width to it.

http://jsfiddle.net/NA9Ye/10/

```
<div id="img_div" style="height: 500px; width: 500px; background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0goKG41........sadasd==);"></div>
```