# Upload Base-64 encoded CSS image to Asp.Net MVC/WebApi

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Referring to the [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1124149)
I have rendered a base-64 encoded image on client side.

```
.even { background: #fff url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhBgASALMAAOfn5+rq6uvr6+zs7O7u7vHx8fPz8/b29vj4+P39/f///wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACwAAAAABgASAAAIMAAVCBxIsKDBgwgTDkzAsKGAhxARSJx4oKJFAxgzFtjIkYDHjwNCigxAsiSAkygDAgA7) repeat-x bottom}
```

I wonder I could not find any link saying how to upload base-64 encoded image to server side.
Is it feasible to send image stream to MVC / Web Api Controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass the base64 string and covert it to image and then save it.
You can refer this question
 [converting a base 64 string to an image and saving it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400173/converting-a-base-64-string-to-an-image-and-saving-it)