# How do I add favicon (html) as href="data:image/svg+xml,..."?

Tags: html, svg, favicon

I want to create a favicon with `type="image/svg+xml"` and `href="data:image/svg+xml,<svg ... "` but when I put the svg behind the `data:image/svg+xml,` there's always giving me an error like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzkUO.png).
Can guys help me the issue?

Comment: https://codepen.io/tigt/post/optimizing-svgs-in-data-uris#its-all-in-the-quotes-1

Comment: omg thanks u so much @morganney

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is embedding background image data into CSS as Base64 good or bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124149/is-embedding-background-image-data-into-css-as-base64-good-or-bad-practice)